# How To Load and Read Configuration in the Play Framework Guice Module

Tags: playframework, guice

Problem:

I understand we can inject the Configuration module in the rest of the Play framework app, but I want to get my `appliciation.conf` information during the module configuration time. How can I do that?

```
   class BaseModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {

    override def configure(): Unit = {
        val onAzure = ??? // < How can I pull configuration here?
        if (onAzure) {
        bind[PersonService].to[AzurePersonService]
        } else {
        bind[PersonService].to[AWSPersonService]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the configuration in a method in `BaseModule` and use `@Provides` annotation to bind what service you want.

```
   @Provides
    def personService(config: Configuration) : PersonService = {
      val onAzure = config.getOptional[Boolean]("cloud.mode.onAzure").getOrElse(false)
      if (onAzure) {
        AzurePersonService
      } else {
        AWSPersonService
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

You can manually instantiate the `Configuration` within your module file.

```
    import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
    import play.api.Configuration


    class BaseModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
    private val logger = Logger(this.getClass)

    override def configure(): Unit = {
        val config = new Configuration(ConfigFactory.load())
        val onAzure = config.get[Option[Boolean]]("cloud.mode.onAzure").getOrElse(false)
        if (onAzure) {
        bind[PersonService].to[AzurePersonService]
        } else {
        bind[PersonService].to[AWSPersonService]
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to be able to override / inject a configuration, e.g. when writing unit tests, you have to inject a Configuration instance into your BaseModule class (using Guice dependency injection). After that you can then craft a Config object and build your test application like so: `myTestConfig = ...; new GuiceApplicationBuilder().loadConfig(myTestConfig)`. myTestConfig will then be injected into your BaseModule class.